# how to port forward to specific api address?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, port-forwarding

seems i've gotten lucky and get to take over some server configuration while the upper echelon finds a replacement!  yay.  love being out of my depth, but upside is, i get to learn new stuff.

anyhow, i have been tasked to setup a port forward to an API address on the web server and i've no idea how to do that.  i know how to port forward, but wholesale, not specifically.  what i need is to be able to redirect `https://catchAPI.somedomain.com` to `https://somedomain.com/APIhandler.php`.

server is running CentOS 8 & Apache 2.4.  i am comfortable with CentOS; Apache, not so much, aside from get it up and running.

i figure the subdomain directory just has to contain the php file?  will a symlink work?  that would be preferable... but i cast myself on your mercies.  :P

Comment: The term you are looking is reverse proxy. Set up it in your Apache 2.4.

Comment: excellent. thank you. Apache Docs here I come!

Comment: Is this question solved?

Comment: not entirely. I've been pointed in a direction. I left it open in the event I need more information.